# Can't read file uploaded by user in containerized Docker application

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I am developing a simple Springboot application which lets a user to upload a file and then read it.

The code works perfectly when I just run the .jar file in my own computer, but when I dockerize it in a docker container, then a FileNotFoundException is thrown.

Here is the code:

```
byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
Path path = Paths.get("./src/main/resources/" + file.getOriginalFilename());
Path path = Paths.get(relPath.toString());
Files.write(path, bytes);
```

(file is a Multipart file received from an HTML form)

I guess ./src/main/resources/ is just in my personal host and not within the Docker Container, but can not figure it out how to solve this problem.

And here is my full simple Dockerfile:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine-jre
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Can you share your dockerfile?

Comment: @AssaelAzran I posted it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine-jre
COPY src/main/resources src/main/resources
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Command `COPY src/main/resources src/main/resources` will copy all resources under `src/main/resources` from your local machine to the container working directory under the same path `src/main/resources` (`src/main/resources` full path will be created inside the container). Since you didn't define any working directory then the root directory is the default (`/`).